# android closing if webview enables javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

When i load google url on webview my app will close.
but if i disable the javascript it will work.
what should i do?
this is the error

sorry if there's error on my question. because i did not always ask question here.

> 12-09 20:42:25.257: E/linker(1282): load_library(linker.cpp:759): library "libmaliinstr.so" not found
>   12-09 20:42:31.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1282): FATAL EXCEPTION: WebViewCoreThread
>   12-09 20:42:31.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1282): java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10151 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
>   12-09 20:42:31.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1282):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
>   12-09 20:42:31.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1282):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
>   12-09 20:42:31.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1282):     at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.isActiveNetworkMetered(IConnectivityManager.java:907)
>   12-09 20:42:31.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1282):     at android.net.ConnectivityManager.isActiveNetworkMetered(ConnectivityManager.java:1065)
>   12-09 20:42:31.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1282):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.isNetworkMetered(WebViewCore.java:692)
>   12-09 20:42:31.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1282):     at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.sharedTimerFired(Native Method)
>   12-09 20:42:31.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1282):     at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.fireSharedTimer(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:92)
>   12-09 20:42:31.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1282):     at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.handleMessage(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:108)
>   12-09 20:42:31.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1282):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>   12-09 20:42:31.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1282):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>   12-09 20:42:31.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1282):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:930)
>   12-09 20:42:31.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1282):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer on my own.

i put     android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE   in my manifest and its work. :D